# Error when setting context... Cannot read property 'input' of undefined'

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

The error is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'input' of undefined'

I am setting the context like so:

```
conv.contexts.set('pgnotes',1000, 
                    {   'pg':pgContext.pg,
                        'notes':response,
                        'lastReferencedPage':-1
                    }
                );
```

I have set contexts using the same general code successfully in other areas.  I'm not sure why it's an error here.

I'v submitted the question to actions on google support but I don't expect them to respond.  Hoping someone here can offer an idea!

Some surrounding code

```
APIGetNotes(pgContext.pg, uniqname).then(
            response=>{
                console.log("conv.contexts %O", conv.contexts);
                console.log("pgContext.pg: "+pgContext.pg);
                console.log("notes: %O",response);
                console.log("About to set context");
                conv.contexts.set('pgnotes',1000, 
                    {   'pg':pgContext.pg,
                        'notes':response,
                        'lastReferencedPage':-1
                    }
                );
                respondBrowseNote(conv);
            }
        ).catch(
            error=>{
                console.log("ERROR getting notes for pg '"+pgContext.pg+"'  Error:'"+error+"'");
                conv.ask("There was an error getting notes, try again later");
            }
        )
```

Comment: This seems particularly odd since there is no `input` property shown either in your code or in `contexts.set()`. Can you update the question to include the full stack trace, more of the surrounding code, and possibly how `pgContext` is defined?

Comment: I'm not aware how to get a stack trace.  This is running in firebase.

pgContext and response both look to be fine to me with regards to their values.